# hibernate repositiory without @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, repository

Can Hibernate recognize entities without declaring neither as @Entity nor in xml configuration?

```
class MyEntity {
    Long id;
}

interface MyEntityRepository implements Repository<Entity, Long> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don't declare entities with the proper annotation in newer Hibernate versions or declare them in the XML, there is no way for the Hibernate framework identify that class as an Entity.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is actually a reason for us to declare the class as entity either in xml or as annotation such that hibernate does persist the objects of that class in the database. So if you don't declare the class as entity then hibernate doesn't even care about the particular class. Wondering why you would want to do that.